# Does allowing a change of source at run time make the code vulnerable to an XSS attack?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I have a requirement to dynamically update the "src" link in the below code with a hyperlink which in turn will point to another .js file.
The following is just an example URL used for "src".
**My questions is, allowing to change 'src' in runtime, does this code become vulnerable to XSS attack?**
If yes, can you please advise which alternate approach can be taken?

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function() {
var customScript = document.createElement('script'); 
customScript.type = 'text/javascript'; 
customScript.async = true; 
customScript.src = 'https://abcd.com/custom_file1.js'; 
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(customScript, s); 
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Does this one belong to code review section ?

Comment: It might be a valid question, just poorly worded. He is actually asking if allowing the source to be changed at run time would cause a vulnerability. Which is a valid question for SO as long as it has not yet been asked.

Comment: Whats the reason for downvote?

Comment: As it was originally worded it sounded like you just wanted a code review. These are off topic on SO and will get down voted until they are either closed or migrated. I edited the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks Isak. My intention is not really a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you're adding a new `<script>` tag, from which the attribute value `src` is determined within your JavaScript, and not by any kind of user input. Therefor this would not be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

This is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks... yes I am not allowing  a user input in this case. I guess in that case this approach is not XSS vulnerable? I was looking for some assurance of my idea!